# How to get DropDownList SelectItem in asp.net mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on application using asp.net mvc 4. Here i have a dropdownlist which is showing some list of amount. My Model Named Search have a variable named Minimum of decimal type which i have shown in dropdownlist as

```
@Html.DropDownList("Minimum", new List<SelectListItem>
                              { 
                            new SelectListItem { Text="Less Than 5000", Value="1"},
                            new SelectListItem { Text="5000", Value="2"},
                            new SelectListItem { Text="10,000", Value="3"},
                            new SelectListItem { Text="15,000", Value="4"},
                            new SelectListItem { Text="20,000", Value="5"},
                            new SelectListItem { Text="25,000", Value="6"},
                            new SelectListItem { Text="30,000", Value="7"},
                            new SelectListItem { Text="35,000", Value="8"},
                            new SelectListItem { Text="40,000", Value="9"},
                            new SelectListItem { Text="50,000", Value="10"},
                            new SelectListItem { Text="60,000", Value="11"},
                            new SelectListItem { Text="70,000", Value="12"},
                            new SelectListItem { Text="80,000", Value="13"},
                            new SelectListItem { Text="90,000", Value="14"},
                            new SelectListItem { Text="1,00,000", Value="15"},
                            new SelectListItem { Text="5,00,000", Value="16"},
                            new SelectListItem { Text="10,00,000", Value="17"}
                              }, new { @class = "selectpicker" })
```

This dropdwonlist is under form tag whose on submit this form goes to action nemed "Display Details" which is as follows

```
public ActionResult DisplayDetails(Search objCust)
{
    objCust.Minimim = Convert.ToDecimal(Request.Form["Minimim"]);
}
```

But here i am getting selected value but not it selected Text. How i can get the selected text Here.

Comment: The set the `Value` property of each `SelectListItem` to the same as the `Text` property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having two option,

**Option 1**. put Value = Text in dropdown

**Option 2**. Take one Hidden field with some Name say "MinimumValue" and before submitting the form store selected dropdown text in hidden field "MinimumValue" then you can get the value as Request.Form["MinimumValue"]

Let me know if you need more help

Comment: It is a fine solution. Thanx