# How to get DropDownList selected Text in MVC controller

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this DropDownList in html where i can select the Texts.Text = Project, Value = ID

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Project", new SelectList(Model.dropConfig, "Project", "ID"), "-- Select LineID --", new { required = true, @class = "form-control" })
```

On click submit button in the controller I can see that the Value (ID) is passed on to be posted back to DB. I want the Text to be post into DB.

Controller side code line:

```
detailsConfig.Project = Convert.ToString(form["Project"]);
```

For example: 
If the dropdownlist values are

```
Project     ID
test        1
testagain   2
```

In controller I should get test, not 1. Please help

Comment: Then use `new SelectList(Model.dropConfig, "Project", "Project")` A `<select>` element posts back the value of its selected option, not its text. Alternatively just query the db to get the value based on the ID

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get DropDownList SelectItem in asp.net mvc 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32138787/how-to-get-dropdownlist-selectitem-in-asp-net-mvc-4)

Comment: @StephenMuecke      `new SelectList(Model.dropConfig, "Project", "Project")`    simple yet effective solution. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new SelectList(Model.dropConfig, "Project", "Project")
```

The above change solves my problem. Thanks @StephenMuecke :)

Answer (score 5):

You use that drop-down change event and store that name in hidden filed and get that value to controller.

**View:-**

```
@Html.DropDownList("Project", new SelectList(Model.dropConfig, "Project", "ID"), "-- Select LineID --", new { required = true, @class = "form-control",@id="ddlProject" })

<input type="hidden" id = "hdnProjectName" name="ProjectName" />
```

**Jquery:-**

```
$("#ddlProject").on("change", function () {
              $("#hdnProjectName").val($(this).find("option:selected").text());
        });
```

**Controller:-**

```
public ActionResult Save(FormCollection formcollection)
{
   var projectName = formcollection["ProjectName"];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should definitely strongly-type your dropdownlist to your model.

What I mean is this...

In the controller is where I would create the selectlist to be used in the view.

---

**Controller**

```
ViewBag.ProjectSelection = new SelectList(/* your data source */, "Project", "Project");
```

> Disclaimer:
>
> Submitting the **Text** value is not preferred because typically the **Text** value of the select element is not **unique**.  Submitting the `ID` to the server is the best practice.. and then you can simply query the database based on the `ID` you submitted to get the values you want.  This is the best way to get the most accurate and reliable data.

---

Then in your view, strongly-type your `ProjectSelection` selectlist to the `Project` property in your model.

**View**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Project, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ProjectSelection, "-- Select LineID --", new { required = true, @class = "form-control" })
```

*Why are you declaring `required` in the dropdownlist?  That should be declared in your model*.

---

**Explanation**

In MVC, when it comes to HTML elements where the user can **select** options to be submitted to the server (dropdownlist, listbox, etc).. only the **Value** will be submitted (which in your case was the `ID`).  The **Text** portion of the element is just for the user to see to make their selection's easier.

---

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: How can I get the `model.Project` value to a FormCollection ?