# How to get dataTextField instead of dataValueField in Dropdownlist in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've sent the viewbag for a cardtype dropdown in a form as follows :

```
var CardType = CommonService.GetCardType();
        ViewBag.CardType = new SelectList(CardType, "Id", "CardType");
```

Now I'm trying to save it in the database as follows :

```
IdCardType = model.IDCardType;
```

This code saves the dataValueField (i.e. "Id"), but I need to save the dataTextField (i.e. "CardType") and I don't know how to do that.
 Can anyone help me out here ?
Thanks

Comment: `ViewBag.CardType = new SelectList(CardType, "CardType", "CardType");`

Comment: Thanks for writing @StephenMuecke ! But isn't there any way to edit this code   "IdCardType = model.IDCardType;"   and get the desired result ?

Comment: That will give you the result - it binds to the value of  `CardType` not `Id`!

Comment: please refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47284093/how-to-get-dropdownlist-selected-text-in-mvc-controller